Question on ARCH effect Test
I try to conduct ARCH effect test.
I have a time series (Global price of Brent crude oil) which follows AR(3).
First of all, I estimate AR(3) model for the Oil price.
$$Y_t = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 Y_{t-1} + \alpha_2 Y_{t-2} + \alpha_3 Y_{t-3}  +e_t $$
Secondly, I obtain  the error terms ($e_t$) of AR(3) model.
Thirdly, I apply Engle's ARCH effect test on these error terms:
$$\hat {e_t}^2 = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \hat {e_{t-1}}^2 +\beta_2 \hat {e_{t-2}}^2 +...+\beta_q \hat {e_{t-q}}^2 $$
Here, how can I decide the order of error terms (q) ?
